# derivative of zero order bessel function of first kind

Tags: derivatives

I want to know the derivative of the zero order bessel function of first kind ($J_0(x)$). and how it changes with $x$ and I also would like to know the roots of this function. could anyone help?

Comment: Did you try to have a look at [Abramowitz and Stregun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_361.htm) (item 9.1.28)?

Answer (score 6):

Let's remember that (as indicated by Did [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_360.htm) is an excellent resource)  :
$$\tag{1}\operatorname{J}_{\nu}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\left(-1\right)^k\left(\frac z2\right)^{2k+\nu}}{\Gamma(k+\nu+1)k!}$$
so that
$$\tag{2}\operatorname{J}_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\left(-1\right)^k\left(\frac z2\right)^{2k}}{\Gamma(k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\left(-\frac {z^2}4\right)^k}{k!^2}$$
and (with $j:=k-1$) :
$$\tag{3}\operatorname{J}'_0(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\left(-1\right)^k \,k\;\left(\frac z2\right)^{2k-1}}{k!\,k!}=-\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac {\left(-1\right)^j \;\left(\frac z2\right)^{2j+1}}{\Gamma(j+2)j!}=-\operatorname{J}_1(z)$$

Concerning the zeros of $\operatorname{J}_0$ and $\operatorname{J}_1$ they are represented in A&S (some numerical values are shown in the table [page 409](http://www.convertit.com/Go/EducationPlanet/Reference/AMS55.ASP?Res=200&Page=409)) :

[image: A&S]
<sub>(source: [math.sfu.ca](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_359.jpg))</sub>

Other useful resources are [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10) and Watson's famous books (freely available) :

- ['A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions'](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.176994/page/n1)
- ['The Zeros of Bessel Functions'](http://archive.org/details/philtrans07851974)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Gary! (btw two of the links are broken, I'll edit them later...)